# Can host buffer be reused after returning from cuMemcpyHtoDAsync?

Tags: cuda

The documentation does not say that explicitly so I am assuming the buffer cannot be reused. But want to make sure if that is the correct assumption.

Comment: you presumably mean a host buffer used as the source in a HTOD copy? But what do you mean by "reuse"?

Comment: The buffer can be reused after the transfer is complete.  It cannot safely be reused before the transfer is complete.  In the case of `cudaMemcpy... **Async**` calls, the return of the call does not indicate that the underlying transfer is complete.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella , that is exactly what I wanted to clarify.

Comment: @talonmies Overwrite the buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is permissible to overwrite the contents of a host buffer which you have used as an argument to an asynchronous host to device transfer, *as long as you take steps to ensure that the transfer has completed*.

The return status alone does not tell you that the transfer is complete. You need to use an explicit synchronization command on the host after the asynchronous copy is launched to confirm this.